# CMake cannot find OpenCVConfig.cmake even after specifying OpenCV_DIR

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm running a C++ program using OpenCV. I've installed all necessary libraries but it seems cmake cannot find OpenCV libraries.

The command `port content opencv3` shows my opencv libraries are under these folders:

`/opt/local/libexec/`

`/opt/local/bin/`

`/opt/local/lib/`

`/opt/local/include/`

but adding `set(OpenCV_DIR /opt/local)` before `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)` didn't work and the same error just pop up every time.

What should I do?

Comment: Not `set(OpenCV_DIR /opt/local)`. `set(OpenCV_ROOT /opt/local)`, maybe.

Comment: I tried your solution, but unfortunatelly cmake reports the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake commands do not separate their arguments via `,`. Thus when you wrote:

```
set(OpenCV_DIR, /opt/local/share/OpenCV)
```

You in fact set a variable named `OpenCV_DIR,` to `/opt/local/share/OpenCV`. You can "fix" it by removing the comma:

```
set(OpenCV_DIR /opt/local/share/OpenCV)
```

I say "fix" because this is not a good way of doing things. Your CMakeLists.txt should be free of absolute paths. Instead, set `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/local` on the command line or in a [preset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I just realized that `locate` is using some old cache and nothing really exists in the folder I mentioned in my previous question. I've just updated my question and please help me out.  The program was able to run a few days ago before I upgraded the macOS system to a newer version, I've tried to reinstall the environment but it's always the same problem.

Comment: @Zheng: So, what is **exact path** to the `OpenCVConfig.cmake` file on your system? Without that file (or `opencv-config.cmake` one) OpenCV cannot be detected by CMake.

Comment: @Alex Reinking: After rebuilding the locate database, it turns out the exact path to `OpenCVConfig.cmake` is `/opt/local/libexec/openvc3/cmake`, and `set(OpenCV_DIR /opt/local/libexec/openvc3/cmake)` worked. I'd like to follow your advice, but I only have some experience with python and am really a noob with C++. I'm using CLion as my IDE and how can I set `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/local` on the command line as your recommendation? Thanks.